# how to undo hijacked files in clearcase?

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

I have this strange hijacked file in my snapshot view. when I undo it, it doesn't go away. Is there a way to un-hijack it. I already tried undo-hijacked but didn't work. I should see .keep file if it unhijacked but didn't see any. Also tried to check out and uncheck out but this file still remains as hijacked.

Thanks for any help !!

Answer (score 0):

There is usually one case where an hijacked file remains hijacked when you try to cancel it (following "[Canceling a hijack](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.doc/topics/t_ccview_unhijack.htm)"):

It is when the file is kept by an handle (it is opened or used by another process).

Try to close as many application / processes (or even reboot the computer), and then try to cancel the hijacked file again.

Answer (score 0):

Another cases that happened , is when the file is somehow with READ-ONLY option on it when it is in Hijacked mode.

So you should removed the READ-ONLY, then undo-hijacked. Now it should be back in READ-ONLY option turned on as it is checked-in.

Enjoy,
Eli.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the file

ct update <path_to_file>