# Check Out vs Hijack file in RAD

Tags: version-control, versioning, clearcase, ibm-rad

Can someone please explain, in layman's terms, the difference between a file 'Check Out' and a file 'Hijack' in Rapid Application Developer IDE?

Comment: Came upon this short and sweet write-up while googling: http://howto.praqma.net/cc/ucmpedia/hijack-files  
Really clarified the answer to my original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both should reference a file in a ClearCase snapshot view used [with  ClearCase SCM Adapter that is included in Rational Application Developer and the optionally installable ClearCase Remote Client Extension](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSRTLW_9.0.0/com.ibm.javaee.doc/topics/rintegratingclearcase.html):

- **checkedout**: ready to be modified (and no-one else can check-in the same file before that checked out file is checked-in, in case of a [reserved checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2950583/6309))
- **hijacked**: [the file is *not* checked out, and yet it is made writable](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21123318) (through OS: chmod or Windows file properties)

An hijacked file needs:

- either to be [checked out (to keep the local modification) and then checked in](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35893254/6309),
- or [canceled](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19150386/6309) (the local modification are lost, and the file is read-only again)

Comment: For checkout, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/24656545/6309 as a concrete example.